# Соединение таблиц внутри скобок. Роль и преимущества

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Столкнулся с незнакомым кейсом, который можно описать простым примером:

```
WITH A AS 
(
  SELECT 1 A, 6 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 A, 5 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 A, 4 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 A, 3 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 A, null B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 A, 1 B FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT '||A1||', A1.*,
       '||A2||', A2.*,
       '||A3||', A3.*
  FROM A A1
  JOIN (A A2
        LEFT JOIN A A3 ON A2.A=A3.B)
    ON A1.A = A3.B;
```

Этот код полностью работает в Оракл 12c, но не работает, например, в импале (без FROM DUAL, конечно).

Суть в том, что я впервые вижу `JOIN` внутри скобок. Причем, эти скобки не получают своего псевдонима и соединяются с другими таблицами со ссылкой на имя одной из таблиц внутри скобок.

Пытаюсь понять, почему так сделано и какие это дает выгоды. Является ли это принуждением оптимизатора выполнить сперва `JOIN` таблиц `А2` и `А3`? Какие преимущества такой `JOIN` может иметь перед традиционным подходом?

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT 1 A, 6 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 A, 5 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 A, 4 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 A, 3 B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 A, null B FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 A, 1 B FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT '||A1||', A1.*,
       '||A2||', A2.*,
       '||A3||', A3.*
  FROM A A1
  JOIN A A3 ON A1.A = A3.B
  LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A2.A=A3.B;
```

Comment: *Является ли это принуждением оптимизатора выполнить сперва джойн таблиц А2 и А3?* Да, именно так. Нередко порядок сканирования таблиц самым радикальным образом влияет на производительность запроса. Некоторые диалекты даже имеют специальные расширения, позволяющие управлять порядком соединения - скобки в Oracle, STRAIGHT_JOIN в MySQL и т.п. *Какие преимущества такой джойн может иметь перед традиционным подходом?* Вы невнимательны - Ваш запрос совершенно неэквивалентен. Как минимум там должно быть RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: @Akina
Я просто сам себя могу переиграть и уничтожить :D Я сперва действительно попробовал с правым джойном, но получил другой результат, от балды попробовал левый и удовлетворился, получив такой же результат :) Буду благодарен, если вы приведете пример "правильного" "плоского" кода. Потому что я сейчас и занят переносом этого запроса в импалу, которая не умеет в скобки и нужно понять правильный алгоритм раскрытия скобок.

Comment: INNER JOIN симметричен. LEFT JOIN желательно не трогать. Само собой надо следить за видимостью - использовать поле таблицы в ON строго после объявления самой таблицы. Посему лучше поместить LEFT JOIN в начало, и получить ```.. FROM A A2 LEFT JOIN A A3 ON A2.A=A3.B INNER JOIN A A1 ON A1.A = A3.B ..```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Роль скобок в соединени трёх и более таблиц та же, что и в любом составном выражении - изменить порядок выполнения. В [документации (см. *join_clause*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDIJFDJ) об этом сказано следующее:

> When you join more than two row sources, you can use parentheses to override default precedence. For example, the following syntax:
>
> ```
>    SELECT ... FROM a JOIN (b JOIN c) ...
> ```
>
> results in a join of `b` and `c`, and then a join of that result set with `a`.

Порядок по умолчанию - слева на право. Причём, оптимизатор вправе изменить этот порядок исходя из условия соединения, наличия индексов и мн. др., но если в соединении есть внешнее (*outer join*), то порядок сохранится, так как результат будет зависеть от порядка выполнения.

Для лучшего понимания, воспроизводимый пример, где порядок выполнения соединений играет роль, он изменяется с заключением одного из соединений в скобки:

```
with t (id, val) as (
    select rownum, column_value 
    from sys.odciVarchar2List ('a', 'b', 'c')
)
select a.id, c.val val  
from t a
left join t b on b.id=a.id and b.val != 'c'
     join t c on c.id=b.id
union all
select null, '#1 ^^^; #2 vvv' from dual
union all
select a.id, c.val val  
from t a
left join (
    t b join t c on c.id=b.id
    ) on b.id=a.id and b.val != 'c';

        ID VAL             
---------- ----------------
         1 a               
         2 b               
           #1 ^^^; #2 vvv  
         1 a               
         2 b               
         3
```